# Kerning of MinionPro footnotefigures with microtype

Tags: footnotes, microtype, kerning, minionpro

I am using the `MinionPro` package and with the option `footnotefigures`. When this option is active, special glyphs are used for footnotes, which look a bit thicker than normal numbers. However, the kerning of these numbers looks quite strange, there seems to be too much space, which becomes relevant once there are more than 9 footnotes. I tried to improve the kerning with custom settings for the `microtype` package, but without success. The kerning just does not seem to function with the `MinionPro-Extra` font, with the normal font everything works fine.

### Update

The problem does not seem to be specific for MinionPro, but occurs for other fonts as well if the encoding is `U`. See the updated MWE.

### Update 2

Added a second MWE without MinionPro.

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}

\SetExtraKerning
[ context = customsetting,
unit = space ]
{ encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,EU1,EU2,TU,TS1,OML,OMS,U},   
    family = {rm*,sf*},
    series = {md*},
    size = {normalsize,footnotesize,small,large}
}
{
    '061 = {,-750}, 
}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{%
    \begingroup
    \microtypecontext{kerning=customsetting}
    \normalfont
    \fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont
    \@thefnmark
    \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent{\microtypecontext{kerning=customsetting}\char'061{}23 \fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont \char'061{}23} \newline
{\microtypecontext{kerning=customsetting} \char'061{}23 \fontfamily{bbm}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont \char'061{}23}
\newline
\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}\footnote{a}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

### MWE - without MinionPro

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}

\SetExtraKerning
[ context = customsetting,
unit = space ]
{ encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,EU1,EU2,TU,TS1,OML,OMS,U},   
    family = {rm*,sf*},
    series = {md*},
    size = {normalsize,footnotesize,small,large}
}
{
    1 = {,-750}, 
}


\begin{document}

{\microtypecontext{kerning=customsetting} 123 
\fontfamily{bbm}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont 123}

{\microtypecontext{kerning=customsetting} 123
    \fontfamily{eur}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont 123
}

{\microtypecontext{kerning=customsetting} 123
    \fontfamily{cmm}\fontencoding{OML}\selectfont 123
}

{\microtypecontext{kerning=customsetting} 123
    \fontfamily{cmsy}\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont 123
}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

First, you specify `family = {rm*,sf*}`, so your kerning is only applied to the font-families specified by `\rmdefault` and `\sfdefault`. You can for example add additional families: With

```
family = {rm*,sf*,MinionPro-Extra},
```

the kerning is also applied for MinionPro-Extra. Of course, you can also use `family = {MinionPro-Extra},` to change only the kerning of MinionPro-Extra  or delete the entire line to affect all families.

The second problem is the encoding: `microtype` uses font sets to restrict the fonts affected by its commands. For details look at the documentation, [4 Selecting fonts for micro-typography](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf). By default, kerning is restricted to the font set `alltext`, so kerning is only applied for the text encodings

```
OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,TS1,EU1,EU2,TU
```

To allow kerning to be added for all encodings, you can enable kerning for the font set `all` by changing

```
\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}
```

to

```
\usepackage[kerning=all]{microtype}
```

Comment: kerning=true/false is imho not the best choice, this threw me off, kerning=alltext, kerning=basictext, kerning=all would be less confusing, thanks for you help